# combine 2 similars list of data frame into one list using a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have 20 data frames related to 10 locations (10 for Male and 10 for Female).I put the same name for my data ( 01M.txt,02M.txt,01F.txt,02F.txt,...10M.txt,10F.txt).
For each data I have 6 variables such as (location,count,Year,Month,day,male(or female)
This is my code

```
  rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))# clear workspace
  setwd("~/NewJob/MyData/")
  library(reshape2)
  require(plyr)
  library(dplyr)

  InputM <- paste0(formatC(1:10, width = 2, flag = "0"),"M.txt")
  InputF <- paste0(formatC(1:10, width = 2, flag = "0"),"F.txt")
  Output <- paste0(formatC(1:10, width = 2, flag = "0"), "Mixed.txt")

 dataM <- list()
 dataF <- list()
 data <- list()

for (i in 1:length(InputM)){
dataM[[i]]<- read.csv(InputTM[i], header = T,sep="\t")}
for (i in 1:length(InputF)){
dataF[[i]] <- read.csv(InputF[i], header = T,sep="\t")}
data[[i]]<- cbind(dataM[[i]],dataF[[i]])
write.table(data[[i]], file = Output[i], sep = "\t",col.names = TRUE, quote = FALSE,    row.names=FALSE)
```

When I run this code I get The dataF duplicated.

I want to have  the  combination of dataM and dataF with 7 variables like this :
location,count,Year,Month,day,male,female) I can put NA when I don't get the corresponding date.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: you are right @beginneR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loop:

```
setwd("~/NewJob/MyData/")
InputM = grep('M', list.files() )
InputF = grep('F', list.files() )

listM = lapply( InputM, function(x){ read.csv(x, head=T, sep='\t')})
listF = lapply( InputF, function(x){ read.csv(x, head=T, sep='\t')})

dataM = do.call(rbind.data.frame, listM)
dataF = do.call(rbind.data.frame, listF)
```

Comment: thank's @Adii_ but this doesn't work. Maybe something is missing in your code !!

Comment: Even the edited answer doesn't work.The ouput must be a list and then I can put it in a data frame using write.table().